# Google API Key restriction on Xamarin MAUI iOS, Android ( Denied Bundle Identifier with Sha-1 )

Tags: android, ios, google-api, api-key, maui

We would like to restrict Google Api Keys in our Xamarin iOS, Android Apps.

When we restrict them from [Google Cloud](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#application-restriction), the api denied our request

Why does it not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause:
I did not provide the right informations during my api request

We add restrictions in [Google cloud](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#application-restriction) on bundle identifiers and the Android Sha-1 signature.

So inside the **Header request**, We need to send this informations

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

//For iOS
Headers.Add("X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier", AppInfo.PackageName) 

//For Android
Headers.Add("X-Android-Package", AppInfo.PackageName)
Headers.Add("X-Android-Cert", DependencyService.Get<ISignatureHashService>().GetSha1() })
```

To get the Sha-1 signature, I used the **DependencyService** that you need to implement it.

```
        public string GetSha1()
        {
            var Context = Android.App.Application.Context;

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.P)
            {
                PackageInfo packageInfo = Context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(Context.PackageName, PackageInfoFlags.SigningCertificates);
                if (packageInfo == null || packageInfo.SigningInfo == null)
                    return string.Empty;

                var signature = packageInfo.SigningInfo.GetSigningCertificateHistory().FirstOrDefault();
                if (signature != null)
                {
                    return SignatureDigest(signature);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                PackageInfo packageInfo = Context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(Context.PackageName, PackageInfoFlags.Signatures);
                if (packageInfo == null || packageInfo.Signatures == null)
                    return string.Empty;

                var signature = Context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(Context.PackageName, PackageInfoFlags.Signatures).Signatures.FirstOrDefault();
                if (signature != null)
                    return SignatureDigest(signature);
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }

        private static string SignatureHexa(Android.Content.PM.Signature signature)
        {
            using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
            {
                var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(signature.ToByteArray());
                var sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);
                foreach (byte b in hash)
                {
                    sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
```

For me My App is Sign by GooglePlay, so I don't need multiple signatures

**But if you need to check multiple signers**

```
if (packageInfo.SigningInfo.HasMultipleSigners)
   {
     foreach (Signature signature in packageInfo.SigningInfo.GetApkContentsSigners())
        {
            //Dostuff
            SignatureHexa(signature);
        }
   }
```

Comment: After a lot of searching this answer finally helped me understand the `Requests from this iOS client application <empty> are blocked.` message that I was getting when calling a Google Cloud API with a restricted key, thank you!